# Unable to fork mongo process

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run mongo process instance with this command :

```
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64 --fork
```

But i am getting the following error :

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 5088
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524925/mongodb-service-wont-start

Comment: check inside 1.log and see what exactly is the cause of error

Comment: Does your `mongod` have permissions to write the data directory?

Comment: Yes that was the issue i had to change the owner of the data directory with chown. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just check whether any other mongod process is running in the os level
use $ ps -ef | grep mongod
and get the pid number of the running mongod process
use $ kill 
and execute the mongod config file freshly