# MongoDB - shutting down with code:100

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to set up MongoDB on my `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)` VPS and I've been running into a few problems. I am running as a user on my server that has `root` access but not using the `root` account itself.

I started to notice the problem when I was executing `db.createUser()` on the `admin` database so I could add other users and I was getting this error:
`not authorized to execute command`

So I then proceeded to uninstall and install again using the tutorial as provided on the website: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Now when I'm on stage **2 Verify that MongoDB has started successfully** on the **Run MongoDB Community Edition** section, that is I look at my output from the file `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, I get the following:

```
2017-04-14T14:23:09.309+0200 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9691 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vps338741
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.3
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-04-14T14:23:09.316+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
2017-04-14T14:23:09.349+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-04-14T14:23:09.349+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-04-14T14:23:09.349+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-04-14T14:23:09.349+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=464M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-04-14T14:23:09.366+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1492172589:366629][9691:0x7f1755946cc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-04-14T14:23:09.367+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I've looked around and it is not the same error [as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100), because that is to do with the fact there isn't an `/data/db` folder which I have. From that log I can see it is something to do with this line:

```
2017-04-14T14:23:09.366+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1492172589:366629][9691:0x7f1755946cc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
```

Which is true, when I go to `/var/lib/mongodb` and do `ls -l` it results with:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Apr 14 14:10 journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Apr 14 14:02 mongod.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Apr 14 14:10 WiredTiger
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb   21 Apr 14 14:10 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1004 Apr 14 14:10 WiredTiger.turtle
```

But I don't know if I should manually create that file as not seen this problem elsewhere. I made sure that `mongodb` user has permissions on these files too as stated [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524925/mongodb-service-wont-start), but still no luck.

I'm really at a loss as to what to do, any help would be very appreciated as this is my like fifth attempt at getting it working!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in MongoDB, check the [report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20729)

Your problem is not that files are missing in general, it's that they go missing when you restart after a clean shutdown. Your problem is not related to the `/data/db` directory but more to `WiredTiger.wt` file that is missing after a restart.

> Oct  1 20:00:44 alpha mongod.27017[1074]: [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   (2) [1443729644:306783][1074:0x7fdba8fd4bc0], file:WiredTiger.wt,
>   connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: No such file or directory

The bug report talks about the same thing.

**Try:**

I would suggest try and disable WiredTiger in the config file.

[MongoDB Config Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

[WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)

**UPDATE:** To disable `WiredTiger` you have to change the `storage.engine` option in your mongo config file, by default mongod uses `WiredTiger` but you can also use `InMemory` [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine)

Comment: This worked, thanks for bringing the issue to light. I've changed my config like so `engine: mmapv1` under the `storage` section as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/satoryu/495913e59bb249b060cc). Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Where is the config file located?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/     - try checking `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: It would be much better if you can share how to disable `WiredTiger` here, instead of redirecting us to another URL :facepalm:

Answer (score 16):

If you created the `mkdir -p /data/db` maybe there is a chance that you must start your server with the following command :  `sudo mongod`

macOS/OSX : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 6):

try :

> sudo service mongod start ;

then run the mongodb with:

> mongo

Answer (score 4):

Make a directory

> sudo mkdir /data/db

Provide access to the directory

> sudo chown -R $USER /data/db

Then run

> mongod

If you get port already in use the stop mongod, it might be running in the background

> sudo service mongod stop

If the last line is

> waiting for connections on port 27017

then the mongod is working

Answer (score 1):

This command helped me:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

Answer (score 1):

## Docker container:

In my case, I was using a docker container running

```
  mongodb:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
    user: root
    command: "chown -R $USER /bitnami/mongodb"
    volumes:
      - '/var/www/mongodb_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=bn_parse
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=3yfQexfqcc
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=bitnami_parse
```

I migrated the docker host to other VPS/VM (aws is too expensive).

I added temporarily the command "chown -R $USER /bitnami/mongodb" to change the owner of that folder /bitnami/mongodb. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

for me the 'answer' was to execute the following command (since `service mongod start` and just `mongod` failed)

```
sudo mongod --fork --port 27017 --replSet admin --logpath /data/log/mongo.log
```

I did not need to turn off wired tiger

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mdkir data/db

sudo service mongod stop

sudo mongod

mongosh
```

this fixed it for me on ubuntu 22.04 after hours and hours of hunting down solutions