# Not able to start MongoDB instance - Starting database mongod [fail]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I downloaded MongoDB on my WSL on Win 11, following the step by step from the Microsoft website.

But when I run the command:

`sudo service mongodb start`

It returns this: **Starting database mongod [fail]**

I don't know what to do, I've tried several things. I already uninstalled and installed again.

I expected Mongo to boot normally, but it doesn't. I can't even get into the Mongo shell.

When I run `mongo`, it returns this:

`mongo Command 'mongo' not found, did you mean: command 'mono' from deb mono-runtime (6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2) Try: sudo apt install <deb name>`

So if I look in my packages, I have it installed:

```
dpkg --list | grep mongo
ii  mongodb-database-tools           100.7.0                                 amd64        mongodb-database-tools package provides tools for working with the MongoDB server:
ii  mongodb-mongosh                  1.8.0                                   amd64        MongoDB Shell CLI REPL Package
ii  mongodb-org                      6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB open source document-oriented database system (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-org-database             6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB open source document-oriented database system (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-org-database-tools-extra 6.0.5                                   amd64        Extra MongoDB database tools
ii  mongodb-org-mongos               6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB sharded cluster query router
ii  mongodb-org-server               6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB database server
ii  mongodb-org-shell                6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB shell client
ii  mongodb-org-tools                6.0.5                                   amd64        MongoDB tools
```

I do not know what to do, Can someone help me?

Comment: Tried any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884233/mongodb-service-is-not-starting-up
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524925/mongodb-service-wont-start
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309575/mongodb-service-failed-with-result-exit-code

Comment: regarding `mongo` not found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403.

Comment: `Starting database mongod [fail]` - you should provide logs